# Angular2 - Read json file synchronously

Tags: json, angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I am refactoring a datepicker control on my form that requires a i18n config object.

What I had was this

```
import {BaseControl} from './base-control';

export class DatePickerControl extends BaseControl<Date> {
  controlType = 'datepicker';

  locale: any = {
    en: {
      firstDayOfWeek: 1,
      dayNames: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
      dayNamesShort: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
      dayNamesMin: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
      monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October',
        'November', 'December'],
      monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
      dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
    },
    nl: {
      firstDayOfWeek: 1,
      dayNames: ['Zondag', 'Maandag', 'Dinsdag', 'Woensdag', 'Donderdag', 'Vrijdag', 'Zaterdag'],
      dayNamesShort: ['Zon', 'Maa', 'Din', 'Woe', 'Don', 'Vri', 'Zat'],
      ... You get it by now
    },
    fr: {
    },
    de: {
    },
    ...
  };

  constructor(options: {} = {}) {
    super(options);
  }

}
```

and I read the configuration in another file and used it in the template:

```
get i18nConfig(): any {
  let val = null;

  if (this.filter instanceof DatePickerControl) {
    const language = this.translateService.currentLang;
    val = <DatePickerControl>(this.filter).locale[language];
  }

  return val;
}

<p-calendar *ngSwitchCase="'datepicker'" [formControlName]="filter.key [id]="filter.key" [locale]="i18nConfig" [dateFormat]="i18nConfig.dateFormat">
</p-calendar>
```

Now I want to maintain all configuration objects in seperate `.xx.json` files.
I know I can use a solution like the following, and it works, **but I don't like it**.

```
import * as i18n_en from './control-translations/datepicker/datepicker.en.json';
import * as i18n_nl from './control-translations/datepicker/datepicker.nl.json';
import * as i18n_fr from './control-translations/datepicker/datepicker.fr.json';

export class DatePickerControl extends BaseControl<Date> {
   ...
  getConfig(lang: string): any {
    switch (lang) {
      case 'nl':
        return i18n_nl;
      case 'fr':
        return i18n_fr;
      case 'en':
      default:
        return i18n_en;
    }
  }
   ...
}
```

Ideally, I would like is something like this but I don't think it is possible;

```
getConfig(lang: string): any {
    return `./control-translations/datepicker/datepicker.${lang}.json`;
}
```

Are there any other solutions which I don't know of that are **SYNCHRONOUS**?
I really don't want to make this piece of code asynchronous. If there's no other way, I will use my previous solution that I don't like very much and it will have to make due...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: to read your file, you need to provide an URL : Angular is launched in a server, it is not supposed to get a direct access to file system. However, static files served with the angular server can be accessed by their URL. Then access your file with http.get()  . Here, a synchronous call makes little sense, are you sure you absolutely require a synchronous call ?

Comment: @Pac0 I'd rather keep things simple stupid on this one so I want to avoid using `http.get()`.

Comment: You can use `require('filename')` to include the contents of a file at **compile time**, so this is not exactly what you want. But you could do something like : feed an object in a service with the various files' data at compile time using `require`. Keys for this object will be the language code you use as parameter. Then, your `getConfig(lang)` function will just access the `service.bigObject[lang]` . I keep this as a comment since it is not a full formatted answer.

Comment: @Pac0 Thanks for the input. I'll reflect on your last comment. I haven't thought of a solution using `require`.